# From which version JRuby will be default to 1.9?

Tags: jruby

Is there a particular version of JRuby in the project timeline when default will be changed to 1.9?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no set plan for that yet, but if there is enough push from the users, I bet Charlie and Tom can be persuaded. I opened http://bugs.jruby.org/6387 for this topic. There is probably enough time for it before the 1.7 release.

Answer (score 4):

JRuby 1.7. And here's the rest of my 30 characters.